# Skip duplicated dots based generated by randint() function

Tags: python

I am still learning Python programming and currently struggling to achieve one goal. I got a class `Dot` that is used to create coordinates and compare them later on. Also, I got a class `Player` with two other child classes that are inherited from the Parent class.

```
class Dot:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y

    def __repr__(self):
        return {self.x, self.y}


class Player:
    def __init__(self, board, enemy):
        self.board = board
        self.enemy = enemy

    def ask(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def turn(self):
        while True:
            try:
                target = self.ask()
                repeat = self.enemy.shoot(target)
                return repeat
            except BoardExceptionError as e:
                print(e)


class Viki(Player):
    def ask(self):
        answer = Dot(randint(0, 5), randint(0, 5))
        time.sleep(3)
        print(f'Turn of Viki: {answer.x} {answer.y}')
        return answer


class Human(Player):
    def ask(self):
        while True:
            h = input('Your turn: ').split()
            if len(h) != 2:
                print('Add 2 coordinates...')
                continue
            x, y = h
            if not (x.isdigit()) or not (y.isdigit()):
                print('Add numbers from 0 to 6...')
                continue
            x, y = int(x), int(y)
            return Dot(x - 1, y - 1)
```

What I would like to expect is that class "Viki(Player)" kind of an AI, forcing it to not use the same coordinates(Dots) that are already used(generated) previously. So, every time it should use none used cells on the board.

I understand that it might help in this case logical operators or count function. For example,

Example 1:

```
a = Dot(1, 2)
b = Dot(1, 3)
c = Dot(1, 4)
abc_list = [Dot(1, 2), Dot(2, 2), Dot(2, 3)]
print(a in abc_list)
Output
True
```

Example 2:

```
print(abc_list.count(a))
Output
1
```

I tried to play with both options but gettings different types of errors when I try to use loops and blocks. I understand that the bottleneck here is my knowledge :) Your help is much appreciated if someone can help me to sort this out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a generator that produces all the dots in random order (no repeats):

```
from itertools import product
from random import shuffle

def random_dots():
    dots = [Dot(*p) for p in product(range(6), repeat=2)]
    shuffle(dots)
    yield from dots

rd = random_dots()
```

Now, you can use it in you code:

```
dot = next(rd)
```

If pre-generating all dots is not an option because there are too many, you could use the following which is lighter on memory/time:

```
dots = set()

def random_dot():
    while (tpl := (randint(0, 5), randint(0, 5))) in dots:
        pass
    dots.add(tpl)
    return Dot(*tpl)
```

And use like:

```
dot = random_dot()
```